# Adobe flex application into Electron

Tags: apache-flex, electron

Is it possible to launch, integrate Adobe flex application within the electron shell?

Have someone done this before? if so, I am looking for challenges or even a possibility of using it with electron.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that you will have to migrate from Adobe (maybe apache?) Flex to the new Royale SDK. This will allow you to export as html5 and then wrap it with electron.

When migrating to [Apache Royale](https://royale.apache.org/), you can keep your as3 code but will have to rewrite most of the UI. There is also an option to "emulate" spark components but I haven't tried that.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention are creating Desktop App, recompile your code with Adobe AIR and re-target for Desktop.
This will be much much much more easier.